# Laravel 5 Unittest call Method Order

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

In what order, does Laravel 5 call test cases inside a single class?

Are they called from top to bottom? Alphabetically? Can I specify the order?

Meaning, I want to test API calls starting from:
POST ( creating an order ),
GET ( reading that newly created order ),
DELETE ( deleting that order ). It would be nice, If I could do that as 3 separate automatic tests, but I don't know, if they will be always executed int that specific order.

Comment: Take a look at this https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.test-dependencies, it doesn't exactly manage the order of the tests but it allows your tests to return data to be used in another test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not relay on the order of the tests, instead do something like:

1. Make a POST request and assert that the post was created.
2. Create an order manually and then make a GET request and assert the order was found
3. Create an order manually and then make a DELETE request and assert the order was deleted.

The data should not persist between tests, use the `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions`or the `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations`.

See more info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test

Comment: I already did something like that: `public function testOrder() { $clientOrderId = $this->order(); $this->assertInternalType('string', $clientOrderId); $this->assertNotEmpty($clientOrderId); $this->OrderStatus($clientOrderId); $this->DeleteOrder($clientOrderId); }` but I wanter to be able to run them seperatel, without making new tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@depends` annotation to ensure one test runs after another, but as @scrubmx pointed out, your tests should not relay on the order of the execution. Otherwise if your `createOrder` tests fails, the rest of the test will not be executed. It's also harder to maintain a growing test suite if the data is created implicitly by another test case, and not explicitly in the one that makes operations on it, as you'll have more and more variations of the data you want to test against.